# How can I decide if I want to return a pair with an integer key or string key inside a template function

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm trying to figure out what type the template currently is, I have looked in stackoverflow but did not find a solid answer. Basically I want to create an `#if #else #endif` and depending on the type of the template put code.

Here is my code

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
#define IS_INT std::is_integral<T::first_type>::value
T create_a_pair()
{
    #if IS_INT
    return std::make_pair(5, typename T::second_type()));
    #else
    return T();
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << create_a_pair<std::pair<int, int> >().first << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_a_pair<std::pair<std::string, int> >().first << std::endl;
}
```

I tried this also but I got a compile time error saying I can't use integer 5 because the type is a string.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T create_a_pair()
{
    if (std::is_integral<T::first_type>::value)
        return std::make_pair(5, typename T::second_type()));
    return T();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << create_a_pair<std::pair<int, int> >().first << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_a_pair<std::pair<std::string, int> >().first << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You want `if constexpr` from C++17. Are you limited to C++98?

Comment: Yes it has to be in c++98 is it not possible?

Comment: Did you consider using [template specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)?

Comment: @Sami It is much more cumbersome. You need to define a `struct` to hold the function as a member function and then partially specialize that `struct` on `std::is_integral<T::first_type>::value` with two implementations of the function accordingly. If `T` is not guaranteed to have a `first_type` member, you also need to add some more boilerplate to enable SFINAE on it. I think it is a waste of effort to go this route. Try, if at all possible, to upgrade to C++17 and the first part becomes straight-forward. Upgrade to C++20 and all of it becomes straight-forward.

Comment: Or alternatively you can define two overloads of the template and SINAE-disable one of them based on the value of `std::is_integral<T::first_type>::value`. I think it should be possible using the return type in C++98 if I remember correctly.

Comment: _Why_ are you limited to C++98?  It's really going to hamper you.

Comment: By the way, you are saying you are limited to C++98, but `std::is_integral` requires C++11 as well.

Comment: Why not simplify the caller's code by passing the 2 types separately instead of as a `std::pair` in the template argument? `template <typename T1, typename T2> std::pair<T1, T2> create_a_pair() { ... }` ... `create_a_pair<int, int>().first ... create_a_pair<std::string, int>().first`

Comment: yes but you can easily implement std::is_integral in c++98 as well.

Comment: @Sami I dropped the `std::pair` part in `create_a_pair<std::pair<int, int> >()` since it seemed a bit redundant. If you really want that to be specified, are there other types of pairs that `create_a_pair` should be able to create? It would be good to know if I need to update the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I need some `type_trait`s from newer C++ standards, I steal them and adapt them to the older standard (if needed).

Example:

```cpp
namespace traits98 {
struct false_type { static const bool value; };
const bool false_type::value = false;

struct true_type { static const bool value; };
const bool true_type::value = true;

template<class T, class U> struct is_same : false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_same<T, T> : true_type {};

template<bool B, class T = void> struct enable_if {};
template<class T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
} // namespace traits98
```

With those, you can easily make overloads:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using namespace traits98;

template <typename F, typename S>
typename enable_if<!is_same<int, F>::value, std::pair<F,S> >::type
create_a_pair() { return std::pair<F,S>(); }

template <typename F, typename S>
typename enable_if<is_same<int, F>::value, std::pair<F,S> >::type
create_a_pair() {
    return std::make_pair(5, S());
}

int main() {
    std::cout << create_a_pair<int, int>().first << '\n';
    std::cout << create_a_pair<std::string, int>().first << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I steal them too :) (I also live in Jurassic World)

Comment: @PaulSanders lol :-) I guess [Boost.TypeTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) would be an alternative but for some reason it's not allowed in some projects. Perhaps there is something in the MISRA C++ Guidelines from 2008 that prohibits it or makes it cumbersome to bring in.

Comment: Perhaps, but I like to minimise my dependencies on external libraries, header-only or otherwise.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm like that too - and I also find the boost documentation really ... not very helpful (or not up to date) most of the time.